STM32 BootLoader Hardfault
hi every one so i got a problem with bootloader in stm32
when i switch from bootloader to application everything is fine but at the middle of the user application at one function i face with hardfault.
this is my initilization at main function
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "BootLoader.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */


/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    Process_Recieved_Information(&analyze_Recieved_Packet);
    Send_Information_InBootLoader_Lib(&Send_Data);

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim4);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim4);
    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE ;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      Send_RxData_To_BootLoader_Lib();

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

this is my function to jump to user application

static void Jump_To_User_Application(void)
{
    /* Set the clock to the default state */
        __disable_irq();

        NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(TIM4_IRQn);

        HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3);
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_DISABLE();

        HAL_DeInit();
        HAL_RCC_DeInit();
        HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim4);
        HAL_UART_DeInit(&huart2);
        
    /* Disable Systick timer */
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = 0;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    /* Clear Interrupt Enable Register & Interrupt Pending Register */
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < sizeof(NVIC->ICER) / sizeof(NVIC->ICER[0]); i++)
        {
          NVIC->ICER[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
          NVIC->ICPR[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        }
    /* Re-enable all interrupts */
    __enable_irq();

/*
    void(*User_App_Reset_Handler)(void) = (void *)(*((uint32_t *)(USER_APP_LOCATION)));
    User_App_Reset_Handler();

*/

    /*
    void(* user_app_1)(void);
        uint32_t temp_msp = *(__IO uint32_t *)PAGE_16_ADDRESS;
        __set_MSP(temp_msp);
        uint32_t user_app_1_rst_handler = *(__IO uint32_t *)(PAGE_16_ADDRESS+4);
        user_app_1 = (void *)user_app_1_rst_handler;
        user_app_1();
*/


    __set_MSP(*(uint32_t *)PAGE_16_ADDRESS);

    // Assign the address of the reset handler to the function pointer
    app_reset_handler = (void *)*(volatile uint32_t *)reset_handler_address;

    // Call the user application's reset handler function to start the application
    app_reset_handler();

}

this is the function that cause hardfault
#define N 32
void SomeFunction() 
{
    for (l = 1; l <= m; l++)
    {
        le = pow(2, l);
        le2 = le / 2;
        ur = 1;
        ui = 0;
        // Calculate sine and cosine values
        sr = cos(PI/le2);
        si = -sin(PI/le2);
        // Loop for each sub FFT
        for (j = 1; j <= le2; j++)
        {
            jm1 = j - 1;
            // Loop for each butterfly
            for (i = jm1; i <= nm1; i += le)
            {
                ip = i + le2;
                tr = REX[ip]*ur - IMX[ip]*ui;
                ti = REX[ip]*ui + IMX[ip]*ur;
                REX[ip] = REX[i] - tr;
                IMX[ip] = IMX[i] - ti;
                REX[i] = REX[i] + tr;
                IMX[i] = IMX[i] + ti;
            }
            tr = ur;
            ur = tr*sr - ui*si;
            ui = tr*si + ui*sr;
        }
}

after 3 times looping i get hardfault at this line :
le = pow(2, l);
HardFault Picture
any idea why this is happening ?
as you can see i disable everything that i used in jump function. idk is there any thing else ?
this is a picture from my FPU situation  :
FPU SITUATION

Can you show SysInit of the app? This error may be caused, for example. if you have set wrong flash latency (when clocking CPU with high frequency). Also, if you enable data cache, but do not flush it. Or may be you have the code compiled for the FPU, but the FPU is not enabled, or stack frame configured wrong and you have FPU used simultaneously both from the app and an interrupt. Etc.


any idea why this is happening ? as you can see i disable everything
that i used in jump function. idk is there any thing else ?

You forgot to set the vector table to the one from the user application.
You need to (assuming that PAGE_16_ADDRESS is 256 aligned):
SCB->VTOR = PAGE_16_ADDRESS;

before calling your application.
If your app is using the standard STM32 startup you need to modify system_stm32YYxx.c file (where YY depends on your micro model) by commenting the set vector table line.

thanks for your answer i changed the vector table offset and the Bootloader program jump to user app successfully but as i said user application face with hardfault the middle of the user application

Then it is not related. Did you enable FPU?

yes i updated my post with fpu situation. if i should do anything else to activate FPU tell me ...

the problem was ram usage, the POW function is a heavy function and by replacing this function with powf problem has been solved.
